# Jasper Report takes a long time to show its data

Tags: java, time, jasper-reports, performance-testing

I have a report which is built by Jasper Report. I use parameters for my requirement conditions. while i run my report for a small size of data (less than 100k records), it's very fast. But, the problem is while i run the data for more than 500k records. My jasper report takes so much time which cannot be predicted when exactly the finishing time is. I had increase java memory both in my local pc and my server, but it doesn't work for me.
What kind of problem that occur in my report? Thanks in advance

Comment: It could be a disk caching issue and the pages are moved to a from cached memory...

Comment: You could try some [Googling](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/539435/extremely-slow-report-performance-problem-solved)